# how to allow geolocation access on cefsharp browser?

Tags: geolocation, webbrowser-control, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I m using cefsharp browser component for my winform app,

And some websites requires geolocation access, but could not find a proper way or a sample code to achive this. how to do that?

reference link I already searched [here](https://cefsharp.github.io/)

Comment: CEF removed support for geolocation quite some time ago see https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=17432 for a related discussion.

Comment: You can try using DevTools to grant permissions https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Browser/#method-grantPermissions http://cefsharp.github.io/api/88.2.x/html/M_CefSharp_DevTools_Browser_BrowserClient_GrantPermissionsAsync.htm https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3165 I've never tried, so no idea if that will work